How to make a nested list with #theme item_list?
I want to make a nested list. I know that I can pass a child render array to #theme item_list but when I pass it that, the nested list has an outer bullet as well, rather than depending on an item from the parent list.
In other words, I want the HTML for the nested item to be like this:
<li>Parent item
  <ul>
    <li>Child item</li>
  </ul>
</li>

(Existing questions are too old and are about D7/6.)
